# What is wikipedia pageid? how to change it into real page url?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm studying the wikipedia API,

[some demo api call](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=meaning&srprop=size%7Cwordcount%7Ctimestamp%7Csnippet)

What is the pageid? How do I change it into a real page url?

I mean `<page pageid="18630637" ns="0" title="Translation" />`, how to change `18630637` into `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The `pageid` is the MediaWiki's internal article ID. You can use the action API's [`info`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Info) property to get the full URL from `pageid`:

[`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&pageids=18630637&inprop=url`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&pageids=18630637&inprop=url)

Comment: I wrote a new answer below, maybe a comment would have been enough... You don't need two API calls, one is enough. Just add "&prop=info&inprop=url" to your original URL:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=meaning&srprop=size%7Cwordcount%7Ctimestamp%7Csnippet&prop=info&inprop=url

Comment: anyway to go the reverse? getting `pageid`/`title` from any given `url`?

Comment: @VikasPrasad: You can use the `titles` parameter instead: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&titles=Stack_Overflow`

Comment: @MatějG. My question is given a `url` can we get `title` or `pageid`?

Comment: @VikasPrasad: Not for general URLs as far as I'm aware. At least not via the API.

Answer (score 146):

You can just use a URL like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=18630637

This is the shortest form, others are also possible:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=18630637

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation?curid=18630637

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=18630637

Note that MediaWiki ignores the page title if you specify a curid, so even

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FooBar?curid=18630637

leads to the same page.

Comment: Excellent and short this (http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=18630637). Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if there is an option to redirect to the _title page URL_?

Comment: @freezed I don't know if there's a way using the wiki URLs, but you can get the title for a page ID from the API: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&pageids=18630637

Comment: I was asking for something like when you match a _redirect page_ like this one:`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Whistling_hare` redirects to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pika`. For this pages param `redirect=no` exists (`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Whistling_hare&redirect=no`). I hope for an URL like `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=186307&redirect=yes`. Actually `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=186307` is by default redirecting to `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pika&curid=186307`

Comment: Only don't get why http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=18630637 loads as non-responsive on mobile device and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation loads responsive 

Comment: How do I get JSON/XML back instead of HTML?

Answer (score 13):

Oh, and you can also get the full page URL in your initial API call if you add "&prop=info&inprop=url":

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=meaning&srprop=size%7Cwordcount%7Ctimestamp%7Csnippet&prop=info&inprop=url