# Getting link from random article

Tags: javascript, wikimedia

I have a function that gets the first section of a random Wikipedia article, but I don't know how to get the actual URL of that article. I've looked around in the WikiMedia API and couldn't find it.

```
getRandomArticle : function() {
    return $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&explaintext&exintro=&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {});
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not as easy as you might think. The API returns pages with internal ID's, and you have to use the API again to get information on the particular page, such as the URL.

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&explaintext&exintro=&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data.query.pages, function(k, v) {
        $.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&pageids='+v.pageid+'&inprop=url&format=json&callback=?', function(url) {
            $.each(url.query.pages, function(key, page) {
                console.log(page); // contains the page data
                var url = page.fullurl; // the url to the page
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WXVZF/)

Comment: Awesome, it works! Just wish WikiMedia didn't have to force us to make 2 API calls for such trivial information...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to [What is wikipedia pageid? how to change it into real page url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168020/what-is-wikipedia-pageid-how-to-change-it-into-real-page-url).

The easiest way?
Just go to `http://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=pageid`.

If you are getting query.result.pageid.extract to get text from the article, then you now the pageid.